# Randomly generate enemies faster and faster Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, math, random, generator

Hey I am using a Spawn function I found for a javascript game I am creating to randomy generate enemies to click on. But it is very slow and I would like it to be able to generate faster and faster.. is it possible to modify this code in that way? the spawn function is at the end of the code.

```
function Gem(Class, Value, MaxTTL) {
            this.Class = Class;
            this.Value = Value;
            this.MaxTTL = MaxTTL;
        };

    var gems = new Array();
    gems[0] = new Gem('green', 10, 0.5);
    gems[1] = new Gem('blue', 20, 0.4);
    gems[2] = new Gem('red', 50, 0.6);

    function Click(event)
    {
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        else event.cancelBubble = true;

        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

        if(target.className.indexOf('gem') > -1){
            var value = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-value'));
            var current = parseInt( score.innerHTML );
            var audio = new Audio('music/blaster.mp3');
            audio.play();
            score.innerHTML = current + value;
            target.parentNode.removeChild(target);

            if (target.className.indexOf('red') > 0){
                var audio = new Audio('music/scream.mp3');
                audio.play();
                endGame("You lose");
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    function Remove(id) {
        var gem = game.querySelector("#" + id);

        if(typeof(gem) != 'undefined')
            gem.parentNode.removeChild(gem);
    }

    function Spawn() {
        var index = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 3 ) );
        var gem = gems[index];

        var id = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1 );
        var ttl = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * parseInt(gem.MaxTTL) * 1000 ) + 1000 ); //between 1s and MaxTTL
        var x = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * ( game.offsetWidth - 40 ) ) );
        var y = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * ( game.offsetHeight -  44 ) ) );

        var fragment = document.createElement('span');
        fragment.id = "gem-" + id;
        fragment.setAttribute('class', "gem " + gem.Class);
        fragment.setAttribute('data-value', gem.Value);

        game.appendChild(fragment);

        fragment.style.left = x + "px";
        fragment.style.top = y + "px";

        setTimeout( function(){
            Remove(fragment.id);
        }, ttl)
    }
        function Stop(interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        function endGame( msg ) {
            count = 0;
            Stop(interval);
            Stop(counter);
            var left = document.querySelectorAll("section#game .gem");
            for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
                if(left[i] && left[i].parentNode) {
                    left[i].parentNode.removeChild(left[i]);
                }
            }
            time.innerHTML = msg || "Game Over!";
            start.style.display = "block";
            UpdateScore();
        }

        this.Start = function() {
            score.innerHTML = "0";
            start.style.display = "none";
            interval = setInterval(Spawn, 750);

            count = 4000;
            counter = null;

            function timer()
            {
                count = count-1;
                if (count <= 0)
                {
                    endGame();

                    return;
                } else {
                    time.innerHTML = count + "s left";
                }
            }

            counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

            setTimeout( function(){
                Stop(interval);
            }, count * 1000)
        };
        addEvent(game, 'click', Click);
        addEvent(start, 'click', this.Start);
        HighScores();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is slow? Where is the method `Spawn` called? It's probably there that you need to tweak and not in the code you show.

Comment: Yes it is the Spawn function that is slow.. I'm sorry i pasted too much code. But yes I do not know how to tweak the spawn function

Answer (score 0):

JS/HTML Performance tips:

1) var gems = new Array(); change to new Array(3);

2) cache all new Audio('...');

3) use getElementById it faster then querySelector('#')

4) prepare var fragment = document.createElement('span'); and cache it, use cloneNode to insert it.

5) fragment.style.left & top change to CSS3 transform: translate(). CSS3 transform use your video card GPU, style.left use CPU...

6) Use only single setInterval and run on all list of fragments.

7) You can make a pool of "fragments" and just show\hide, it will increase performance dramatically.

Basically it works slow due to many page redraws, every time you add new elements to page browser must to redraw whole screen, do not add elements, just show\hide them.

Comment: Great thanks! Only don't totally get 6 and 7.. can you please explain?

Comment: 6) make one single setInteval which can iterate on all fragments and "remove"(hide) expired elements once at 100ms.

7) you can make a pool of "fragments" lets say 1000, add class "hide" to them and add all this elements to body, when you need to spawn a new just find one of hidden fragments, fix it position and remove class hide. When you remove() just add "hide" class.